# WPF - Trigger on ColumnHeader's displayIndex greater than value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers, datagrid

I am looking for way to make trigger on datagrid that display context menu when clicked on header, which has DisplayIndex greater than 2.

This is what I have now:

```
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DisplayIndex"  Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                                 Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenu1}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

**Is there any way to do that?** Reason why I need this is that user will add columns dynamicly so he will need (sometimes) delete them.

Comment: So you have at least 2 columns in the collection and user can add additional columns, if you can hold the reference to the newly created columns, find the style with code-behind and attach it to the new columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled this in other way. The code might be usefull:

xaml:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown"  Handler="DataGridColumnHeader_MouseRightButtonDown" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Code behind:

```
private void DataGridColumnHeader_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).DisplayIndex < 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            var x = DataContext as BrygadzistaViewModel;
            x.ColumnHeaderToDelete = ((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).Content.ToString();

            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = "Usuń";
            mi.Command = x.DeleteDay;
            cm.Items.Add(mi);

            cm.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

Wonder if there is better way to to this ;)